# Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to use the [SqlConnection](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection/) class inside a UWP project that is part of a Xamarin Forms application.  I need a reference to the System.Data.DLL which I have added.  However, when I try to create a `SqlConnection` like so:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(queryString))
{

};
```

I get the error  `Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found.`

I am able to declare a SqlConnection variable like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
```

I only get the error when I attempt to use the object. Such as in the `using` statement.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Other similar questions on the site did not seem to help my situation.

Answer (score 1):

On code source from Microsoft says:

> The sample demonstrates how to access data from SQL Server database in
>   Windows Store app. We cannot access SQL Server Database from Windows
>   Store app directly. We have to create an Service layer to access the
>   database.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec#content